# typeof class with generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm designing a small API.  In it, developers define a class, and a configuration file that allows them to use it with my system.

Below is a simplification of my code:

```
abstract class Box<T> {
    constructor(protected initialValue: T) {}

    public abstract getDefaultThing(): T;
}

type BoxType = typeof Box;

interface Config {
    boxType: BoxType;
    initialValue: any;
}

function loadConfig(config: Config) {
    // Need to "as any" this so TSC doesn't complain about abstract class
    return new (config.boxType as any)(config.initialValue);
}
```

Here I define abstract class `Box` with generic parameter `T`.  I also provide an interface for writing their configuration object that wants a reference to the instantiable Box class, as well as an initialValue.  Finally a small implementation function that loads the config by making a new instance of the Box with the value `initialValue`.

A simple use of this would look like this:

```
class MyBox extends Box<string> {
    public getDefaultThing(): any {
        return `${this.initialValue} world`;
    }
}

const config: Config = {
    boxType: MyBox,
    initialValue: "hello",
};

const loaded = loadConfig(config);

console.log(loaded.getDefaultThing()); // prints "hello world"
```

This already doesn't work - `boxType` in `config` has an error because `MyBox` is more narrow than `Box`.  That's fine, what I'd really like to do is redefine my `Config` interface to type-check `initialValue` and `BoxType`:

```
type BoxType<T> = typeof Box<T>;

interface Config<T> {
    boxType: BoxType<T>;
    initialValue: T;
}
```

This doesn't work... at all...  `Box` is already a type, and can't accept generics without being instantiated.  I know on some level I'm mixing values and types, **but is there any way to have a property be a reference to an instantiable generic class narrowed to a certain generic type?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all works out nicely if you don't use `typeof Box` but instead type `BoxType<T>` as a constructor signature that accepts `T` and returns a `Box<T>`

```
abstract class Box<T> {
    constructor(public initialValue: T) {}

    public abstract getDefaultThing(): T;
}

type BoxType<T> = new (initialValue: T) => Box<T>;

interface Config<T> {
    boxType: BoxType<T>;
    initialValue: any;
}

function loadConfig<T>(config: Config<T>) {
    return new config.boxType(config.initialValue); // no cast 
}

class MyBox extends Box<string> {
  public getDefaultThing(): string { // there was a typo here this was any
      return `${this.initialValue} world`;
  }
}

const config = { // no explcit type needed
  boxType: MyBox,
  initialValue: "hello",
};

const loaded = loadConfig(config); // loaded is Box<string>

console.log(loaded.getDefaultThing()); // prints "hello world"
```

If you want `loadConfig` to return the derived type not just the abstract type (ie `MyBox` not `Box<string>`. You need an extra generic parameter:

```
abstract class Box<T> {
    constructor(public initialValue: T) {}

    public abstract getDefaultThing(): T;
}

type BoxType<T, TBox extends Box<T>> = new (initialValue: T) => TBox;

interface Config<T, TBox extends Box<T>> {
    boxType: BoxType<T, TBox>;
    initialValue: any;
}

function loadConfig<T, TBox extends Box<T>>(config: Config<T, TBox>) {
    return new config.boxType(config.initialValue); // no cast 
}

class MyBox extends Box<string> {
  public getDefaultThing(): string { // there was a typo here this was any
      return `${this.initialValue} world`;
  }
}

const config = { // no explcit type needed
  boxType: MyBox,
  initialValue: "hello",
};

const loaded = loadConfig(config); // loaded is MyBox

console.log(loaded.getDefaultThing()); // prints "hello world"
```

Comment: My actual use case is waaayyyy more complicated than what I've got up there (`Box` actually inherits from `React.Component` and has to let state AND props fall-through) and this STILL worked perfectly.  Great answer!